# Is there a way to reach that second path in Macalania Temple?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

When you're making your way to the temple you see this ice path in the back, I'm wondering if it is at all possible to reach it because it seems a bit off to add it there when the rest of the area is devoid of anything else.

Edit:  as per  Adam Jensen's request I couldn't get a screenshot since I have yet to configure a PS2 Emulator or find a non-artwork image of the 2nd path however i did find this:

[Macalania Temple Let's Play](http://youtu.be/eLsV0TI6UG0?t=2m24s)

In the video above you'll see the path I'm talking about, you can also check out the rest of the video to see more of the path. It is this second path I am talking about.

Comment: Isn't that where you will be walking when you are leaving the place? Too long ago for me, need to play again :P.

Comment: @Kevin nope, you enter and leave the temple via the same path, this back path that you see seems to come out from the back of the temple and lead to the bottom of the late, i think you can also see it when your on Sin's back after you've escaped but it still a bit away so it's not connected to where you land

Comment: Could you produce a screenshot of this path?

Answer (score 1):

After you get full control of the airship, you can revisit the temples. If you try to go to the room where you would receive the summon, you'll end up taking that path.

Comment: Note that if you are playing the international or the HD Remaster versions, you must defeat Dark Shiva before you can enter the temple again.